# python numpy probability output

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

using python 2.7 and numpy i want to be able to print test results based on a probablity percentage. based on 10 events i want to print out true if it passed and false if it failed.  Below is pseudo code

```
import numpy as np
probability = .33
```

i'm struggling how to implement using the probablity variable in determining if a test has passed. So in this case the probablity of a test passing 'True' is 33 percent. The probablity does not change for each iteration. its always going to be .33 percent

Ideally it should return something like this

```
false
false
fasle
true
false
true
fasle
fasle
true
true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in `random` and generate a number between 0 and 1 (uniform distribution, so all numbers between 0 and 1 are "equally likely"). Then test if that number is less than your desired probability:

```
import random
def uniform_trials(probability, num_trials):
    for _ in range(num_trials):
        print(probability < random.uniform(0, 1))
```

Then just call `uniform_trials(.33, 10)` for your desired example (or any other `probability` and `num_trials` you'd like to output).